# Selenium error message "selenium.webdriver has no attribute execute script"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, driver

I am using selenium to scrape an infinite scrolling page.

I am trying to use this code:

```
import time
import pandas as np
import numpy as np

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=csubwaystats%20since%3A2018-05-28%20until%3A2018-08-28'

browser.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

# Get scroll height
last_height = webdriver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    webdriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = webdriver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

I obtained this code from multiple sources, the most recent being:

[How can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python/47202073#47202073)

I updated it to include "webdriver" instead of "driver" because I import selenium as webdriver. It doesn't work otherwise.

My issue is that when I run the code I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'execute_script'
```

I don't really understand what this means and how to fix it? I haven't been able to find information on this.

I am new to python and so am probably missing something obvious but any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: please update the question with the exact code you use

Comment: Just did so. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`webdriver` is the name of the module, not your instance of it.  In fact, you assigned the instance you created to the name `browser` with this line: `browser = webdriver.Chrome()`

so instead of calling `webdriver.execute_script()` (which will give you an `AttributeError`), you must call it using your instance, like this: `browser.execute_script()`.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work you have to create an instance of webdriver, e.g.:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome() # webdriver.Ie(), webdriver.Firefox()...
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
```

You can download Chromedriver from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.41/)

You also need to [add path to Chromedriver to your environment variable PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436598/getting-chrome-to-launch-via-selenium) or just put downloaded file into the same folder as your Python executable...

Comment: Ahh, that's my bad. I didn't include the code where I did just this. I have     from selenium import webdriver driver = webdriver.Chrome('location of chromedriver')    ... and then I continued with what was above

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how to format comments properly

Comment: @agra94 , you should not just define `driver`, but use it in following lines (note that I used `driver.execute_script()`, not `webdriver.execute_script()`)

Answer (score 1):

```
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'execute_script'
```

You are getting this error because 'execute_script' is not a *class attribute*, you just can not use it directly. Since it is an *instance attribute* you should create an instance of the class. Please check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) to learn more about *classes*.

This will work fine now since 'execute_script' is *running as an instance attribute*.

```
last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
```

Your final code would have looked like this:

```
import time
import pandas as np
import numpy as np

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=csubwaystats%20since%3A2018-05-28%20until%3A2018-08-28'

browser.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

# Get scroll height
last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    webdriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = webdriver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Comment: *"Do not import selenium as webdriver, import webdriver from selenium"*... Considering exception log OP has already imported `webdriver` *from* `selenium`. *"You need the webdriver class"*... `webdriver` is not a *class*, but module where `WebDriver` class is defined. *"selenium is a python program that has python classes in it"*... No comments :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I did use 'from selenium import webdriver' (without the quotations of course) I also did create an instance of webdriver but I use chrome. I have it in my path as well.

Comment: @Andersson Please forgive my ignorance about that, I'm a student who is trying to give answers which my efforts in them. I should not have bring up things I do not know though.

Comment: @agra94 Well, I am sorry that I did not read your question properly. It is abvious that you already can automate stuff with Chrome, it is my bad.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I have fixed indentation.

Answer (score 0):

For others check your function name. For me I wrote Java function name not the Python one

```
driver.execute_script("script") # Python
driver.ExecuteScript("script"); # Java
```

Posting this here because its the top google result for the error