# Opening USA Clothing website with selenium python redirects me to the Europe Clothing Website home-screen

Tags: python, url, redirect, selenium-webdriver, https

When trying to open a certain URL where a jacket is shown with selenium-python the page automatically redirects me to the European home-screen

Here's my code (USA store):

```
URL = 'https://shop-usa.palaceskateboards.com/products/reversible-spherie-jacket-gold-petrol'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(URL)
webbrowser.open(URL)
```

Website redirects me once I open that URL to this one (European store)

```
https://shop.palaceskateboards.com/
```

Is there any way to stop it from redirecting me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium with scrapy for dynamic page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page)

Answer (score 0):

Disable javascript

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option( "prefs",{'profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript': 2})
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
url='https://shop-usa.palaceskateboards.com/products/reversible-spherie-jacket-gold-petrol'
browser.get(url)
```

Comment: @Redfactor Give the path to chromdriver in executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver'

Comment: File "C:\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @Redfactor On windows executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver.exe' - '.exe' is required

Comment: Ok sorry im new to this so where do i go then to add the executable you added

Comment: @Redfactor First find the path to the chromedriver.exe that you downloaded. The add it in this line browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options) instead of /path/to/chromedriver

Comment: C:\Users\sally\Downloads\chromedriver_win32(1).exe . If possible rename it to chromedriver and use C:\Users\sally\Downloads\chromedriver.exe

Comment: browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/sally/Downloads/chromedriver_win32(1)',chrome_options=chrome_options)   is this ok?

Comment: @Redfactor webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/sally/Downloads/chromedriver_win32(1).exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)

Comment: PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied gave me erro

Comment: @Redfactor I can't help you more than this. Copy it to the same folder as your python file and use  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver_win32(1).exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)

Comment: rip copied it to the same file as my python folder  dosn`t work

Comment: @Redfactor I can't see your system. So i may not be able to solve this for you. You need to find the path to an executable file (.exe) (chromedriver) and add it to your executable_path.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436598/getting-chrome-to-launch-via-selenium